# Change separator in VBA ms-access export module

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using the below code to export a query in a specific txt format, setup so it can be imported into another program. However I can't seem to figure out now to force the output to be Dot "." separated instead of my own locale which uses Comma "," as a separator (the query in the database has the data shown as commas). Basically I need all the commas changed to dots when running the export (perhaps excluding the 'anm' column)

The left is as it should be, the right is what it is currently.

[image]

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function fnTransposeToTxt()

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fd As DAO.Field
    Dim fnum As Integer
    Dim path As String
    Dim OK As Boolean
    Dim var As Variant
    ' export to this file
    path = CurrentProject.path & "\Export.txt"
    
    fnum = FreeFile
    
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("VBK_Knude", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    
    With rst
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            .MoveFirst
            
            OK = True
            
            Open path For Output As fnum
            
        End If
        Do Until .EOF
            For Each fd In .Fields
                var = fd.Value
                Select Case fd.Name
                    Case "Z_F", "DEPTH", "OB", "PERPEND", "Q"
                        var = Format$(Val(var & ""), "0.00")
                    Case "DIMENSION"
                        var = Format$(Val(var & ""), "0.000")
                    Case "CATCHMENT"
                        var = Format$(Val(var & ""), "0.0000")
                End Select
                Print #fnum, fd.Name & " " & var
            Next
            .MoveNext
            If Not (.EOF) Then
                Print #fnum, ""
            End If
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    If OK Then
        Close #fnum
    
        MsgBox "table imported to " & path
    End If
                    
    
End Function
```

Edit: New working code below based on answers.
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

```
Public Function fnTransposeToTxt()

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fd As DAO.Field
    Dim fnum As Integer
    Dim path As String
    Dim OK As Boolean
    Dim var As Variant
    ' export to this file
    path = FilToSave
    
    fnum = FreeFile
    
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("VBK_Knude", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    
    With rst
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            .MoveFirst
            
            OK = True
            
            Open path For Output As fnum
            
        End If
        Do Until .EOF
            For Each fd In .Fields
                var = fd.Value
                Select Case fd.Name
                    Case "AFLKOEF"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.0")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    Case "XY", "TEXTXY", "Z_F", "DYBDE", "OB", "PERPEND", "Q", "STATION", "PERPEND", "AFSTRØM"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.00")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    Case "DIMENSION"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.000")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    Case "OPLAND"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.0000")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                End Select
                Print #fnum, fd.Name & " " & var
            Next
            .MoveNext
            If Not (.EOF) Then
                Print #fnum, ""
            End If
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    If OK Then
        Close #fnum
    
        MsgBox "table imported to " & path
    End If
                    
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `Format` function of MS Access VBA won't let you specify the decimal separator to use. It will *always* use the regional settings of the current user. The only way to fix this is to *manually* replace the decimal separator with the one you use, for every single value.

Thus,

```
var = Format$(Val(var & ""), "0.00")
```

becomes

```
var = Format$(Val(var & ""), "0.00")
var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
```

For completeness, the only other option I am aware of would be to use `Str` to convert the number to a string, which will, contrary to `Format`, always use the dot as the decimal separator. Unfortunately, `Str` does not allow you to specify the number of digits after the decimal point, so this will probably not be an option for your use case.

Comment: Appreciate the help, I've added the Replace section underneath each as you described (see edited code). However my XY, Dybde, TextXY do not have the dot as separator. I'm trying to figure out how to implement it there as well.

Comment: @FoolzRailer: Please don't update code with suggestions from the answers, as this will give the impression that the answers are wrong. I have taken the liberty of reverting you last edit. Regarding your other fields: You can add a `Case` clause for those fields and do the replacement there as well.

Comment: That makes sense, if I want to show the code changes, should I do it as the new edit instead I just put in? 
Also when I do the replace function, it sets everything after the Comma/Dot too zero. So if the Z_F was 65,44 it comes out in the export as 65.00 instead. 
Correction it actually did that before I added the Replace command, just didn't notice till now.

Comment: I think I fixed the issue, appreciate the help!

Comment: @FoolzRailer: Glad to hear that it worked and that I was able to help! Regarding your question about code changes: StackOverflow is not really well suited for "back-and-forth" improving code in multiple steps, it's designed for "single, focused question" -> "single, focused answer" scenarios, where you create a new question for follow-up issues. Your new edit is fine, I think that's the best compromise.